# How to DROP PRIMARY KEY from Column in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a one more question about T-SQL

I´d like to DROP a PRIMARY KEY in database `[COST_mesta_test].[dbo].['1965$']` ,table `'1965$'`

I have primary key on column `obec` (it´s `varchar` column) and this doesn´t work

```
ALTER TABLE [COST_mesta_test].[dbo].['1965$'] 
DROP CONSTRAINT obec
```

It´s give me an error

> 'obec' is not a constraint. Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 Could
>   not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Really don´t know why, because 'obec' is really PK.

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: [First link I got from google](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/12/sql-server-how-to-drop-primary-key-contraint/)

Comment: Your **column** is called `obec` - but your **CONSTRAINT** might be called something else entirely! It's often called `PK_(tablename)` or something like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your primary key isn't likely to be the name of the constraint.

You can use `exec [COST_mesta_test]..sp_help '1965$'` to find the name of the constraint (it will be in the last line of the results).